# How do I access this variable? (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, shopify

Just a simple question:

I am working with Shopify API and rails.

I have this variable:

```
<%=order.shipping_lines%>
```

It's value is:

```
[#<ShopifyAPI::ShippingLine:0x00000003ac6388 @attributes={"id"=>39782416397, "title"=>"canadapost-overnight", "price"=>"8.66", "code"=>"ON", "source"=>"Some new name", "phone"=>nil, "requested_fulfillment_service_id"=>nil, "delivery_category"=>nil, "carrier_identifier"=>"8ae044ada4106c34b8d9463a6f686d1f", "discounted_price"=>"8.66", "tax_lines"=>[]}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=true>]
```

I'm trying to get the "title" or "code".

I've tried with **order.shipping_lines.title** but it doesn't work. How can I obtain the attribute "title"?

Comment: You should post your error, which is something along the lines of `No Method ...` (since you're trying to call an instance method on an `array` (or, more likely, an ActiveRecord collection, given `order.shipping_lines`)). And then think about why calling an instance method on an `array` (or AR `collection`) throws that error...

Comment: @jvillian aarg, I feel so dumb, of course, the solution is **order.shipping_lines[0].title**. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Glad to help. Posted as an answer. Please feel free to upvote and/or accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you figured out, the answer is something along the lines of:

```
order.shipping_lines[0].title
```

However, I would offer that it's a bit more idiomatic (IMO) to say:

```
order.shipping_lines.first.title
```

Naturally, if you want to iterate those, it would be something along the lines of:

```
<% order.shipping_lines.each do |shipping_line| %>
  <%= shipping_line.title %>
<% end %>
```